# Error trying to migrate to Bing Maps v8 from v7

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bing-maps

I'm trying to migrate from Bing Maps v7 to v8 and I've run into an error. It's odd because the error changes slightly if I try async vs synchronously. I've scoured StackOverFlow and Google but can't seem to nail this one down.

If I try async, the error I get is:

> *Uncaught ReferenceError: Microsoft is not defined*

If I try synchronously, the error I get is:

> *Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'road' of undefined*

Like many others I've found reference to, I have used the Bing developer sight and the code works fine, no problems. On my site, not so much. Our site is Asp.net MVC based.

I found a page somewhere that suggested I put the following code in the head section and I've done that too.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Nothing I do seems to work. Here's my code pertaining to the map:

```
<div style="float:left" id='myMap'></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=getMap' async defer></script>
    function getMap() {
        var mapOptions = { credentials: 'MY ACCESS KEY',
            height: 600,
            width: 650,
            mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.Road,
            showMapTypeSelector: true,
            enableClickableLogo: false,
            enableSearchLogo: false
        };
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), mapOptions);
    };
```

I've tried commenting out almost the whole page just to see if I could get something to show up and I still get the same error messages. Clearly I'm missing something for reference but can't seem to figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Here's the complete cshtml file code if that helps:

```
 @model EspexWeb.Models.JobMapInformation
@using EspexWeb.Models
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Map Information";
}
<div class="pagebanner">Job Map</div>
@if (AccessHelper.IsMember("Administrators,Sales,Contact_Admin,Jobsite_Super"))
{
    <div style="float:left; cursor: pointer;" data-bind="click: saveLocation"><img title="Save changes." src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/save.png")" alt="Save" /></div>
}
<div style="float:left; cursor: pointer;" data-bind="click: printdiv, visible: tabID() == 'ui-id-2'"><img title="Print Route." src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/print_48.png")" alt="Print" /></div>
<div style="float:left; cursor: pointer;" data-bind="click: findLocation, visible: tabID() == 'ui-id-1'"><img title="Find Location." src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/find_location_48.png")" alt="Find" /></div>
<div style="float:left; cursor: pointer;" data-bind="click: getDirections, visible: tabID() == 'ui-id-2'"><img title="Map Route." src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/route_48.png")" alt="Route" /></div>
<div style="float:left; margin-left:40px">
        <span class="label3">Job Number:</span><span class="value3 spanlink" data-bind="click: backToJob">@Model.JobNumber</span><span style="margin-left:25px" class="label3">Job Name:</span><span class="value3 spanlink" data-bind="click: backToJob">@Model.JobName</span>
</div>
@if (ViewBag.ReturnUrl != null)
{
        <div data-bind="click: backToValidation" style="float:right; cursor: pointer"><img title="Click here to return to Validation." src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/Validate_48.png")" alt="Validation" /></div>
}
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="errorMessages" class="validation-summary-errors"></div>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1"><span>Address</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1"><span>Directions</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <div style="float:left; margin-right:10px; width:220px; min-height: 100px;">
        <div class="busyindicator"></div>
        <form id="findlocation" action="">
            <div id="address">
                <div id="location">
                    <div>Street</div>
                    <input id='street' name='street' style="width:200px" data-bind="value: street" />
                    <div>City</div>
                    <input id='city' name='city' style="width:200px" data-bind="value: city" />
                    <div>State</div>
                    <input id='state' name='state' style="width:100px" data-bind="value: state" />
                    <div>Zip Code</div>
                    <input id='zipcode' style="width:100px" data-bind="value: zipcode" />
                    <div>County</div>
                    <input id='county' style="width:200px" data-bind="value: county" />
                    <div>Country</div>
                    <input id='country' style="width:200px" data-bind="value: country" />
                    <div>Longitude</div>
                    <input id='longitude' style="width:200px" readonly="readonly" data-bind="value: longitude" />
                    <div>Latitude</div>
                    <input id='latitude' style="width:200px; display: block;" readonly="readonly" data-bind="value: latitude" />

                </div>

                <div id="instructions" style="margin-top: 10px">
                    <div>Special Instructions</div>
                    <textarea id="specialinstructions" rows="10" cols="25" data-bind="value: specialInstructions"></textarea>
                </div> 

            </div>
        </form>
            <div id="directions" style="display: none">
                <div>Street</div>
                <input id='startstreet' style="width:200px" />
                <div>City</div>
                <input id='startcity' style="width:200px" />
                <div>State</div>
                <input id='startstate' style="width:100px" />

            </div>               
        </div>
        <div style="float:left" id='myMap'></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=getMap' async defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var map = null;
    var query;
    var start;
    var viewModel = {
        id: '@Model.ID',
        jobNumber: '@Model.JobNumber',
        jobName: '@Model.JobName',
        street: ko.observable('@Model.Street'),
        city: ko.observable('@Model.City'),
        county: ko.observable('@Model.County'),
        state: ko.observable('@Model.State'),
        country: ko.observable('@Model.Country'),
        zipcode: ko.observable('@Model.ZipCode'),
        longitude: ko.observable('@Model.Longitude'),
        latitude: ko.observable('@Model.Latitude'),
        specialInstructions: ko.observable(@(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SpecialInstructions)))),
        returnUrl: '@Html.Raw(ViewBag.ReturnUrl)',
        tabID: ko.observable(0)

    }
    viewModel.showDirections = function () {
        if ($("#directions").is(":hidden")) {
            $("#address").slideUp("slow", function () {
                $("#directions").slideDown("slow");
                });
        }
    };

    viewModel.showAddress = function () {
        if ($("#address").is(":hidden")) {
            $("#directions").slideUp("slow", function () {
                $("#address").slideDown("slow");
            });
        }
    };

    viewModel.getModelData = function() {
        var map = {
            ID: viewModel.id,
            JobNumber: viewModel.jobNumber,
            JobName: viewModel.jobName,
            Street: viewModel.street(), 
            City: viewModel.city(), 
            State: viewModel.state(),
            County: viewModel.county(),
            ZipCode: viewModel.zipcode(),
            Country: viewModel.country(),
            Longitude: viewModel.longitude(),
            Latitude: viewModel.latitude(),
            SpecialInstructions: viewModel.specialInstructions()};

        return ko.toJSON(map);
    };

    viewModel.backToJob = function () {
        location.href = '@Url.Content("~/JobInformation/JobDetail/?id=")' + viewModel.id;
    }

    viewModel.backToValidation = function () {
        location.href = viewModel.returnUrl;
    }

    viewModel.saveLocation = function () {
        //Display busy indicator to show user something is happening on the server
        $(".busyindicator").show();
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: '@Url.Content("~/JobInformation/SaveMap/")',
            data: viewModel.getModelData(),
            type: "post",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {
                //Allow the user to leave the page without warning
                window.onbeforeunload = null;
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("The server returned the error code: " + result.status + '\n' + "Message: " + result.statusText + '\n' + result.responseText);
            },
            complete: function () {
                $(".busyindicator").hide();
            }
        });
    };

    viewModel.updateInputScreen = function (tabid) {
        if (tabid === "ui-id-1") {
            viewModel.showAddress();
        }
        else {
            viewModel.showDirections();
        }
        viewModel.tabID(tabid);
    };

    function printdiv() {
        w = window.open();
        //Include the style sheets that format the map directions properly
        w.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" rev="stylesheet" href="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/v7.0/css/bin/7.0.2011100111334.47/en/mapDirections.css">');
        w.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" rev="stylesheet" href="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/v7.0/css/bin/7.0.2011100111334.47/en/mapdelay.css">');
        w.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" rev="stylesheet" href="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/v7.0/css/bin/7.0.2011100111334.47/en/mapcontrol.css">');
        w.document.write($('#jobinfo').html());
        w.document.write(viewModel.specialInstructions());
        w.document.write($('#output').html());
    };

    function getMap() {
        // Set the map and view options, setting the map style to Road and
        //    removing the user's ability to change the map style
        var mapOptions = { credentials: 'MY ACCESS KEY',
            height: 600,
            width: 650,
            mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.Road,
            showMapTypeSelector: true,
            enableClickableLogo: false,
            enableSearchLogo: false
        };
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), mapOptions);

        if (viewModel.longitude().length == 0 || viewModel.longitude() == null) {
            getCurrentLocation();
        }
       else {
           setJobPushpinLocation();
        }

    };

    function setJobPushpinLocation() {
        var location = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(viewModel.latitude(), viewModel.longitude());
        var pushpinOptions = { draggable: true };
        var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(location, pushpinOptions);
        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin, 'dragend', endDragDetails); 
        map.entities.push(pushpin);
        map.setView({zoom: 15, center: location });
    }


    function getCurrentLocation() {
        var geoLocationProvider = new Microsoft.Maps.GeoLocationProvider(map);
        geoLocationProvider.getCurrentPosition({ showAccuracyCircle: false });
    };

    function findLocation() {
        if ($("#findlocation").valid()) {
            var street = document.getElementById("street");
            var city = document.getElementById("city");
            var state = document.getElementById("state");

            query = street.value + ' ' + city.value + ', ' + state.value;
            deletePushpin();

            map.getCredentials(callSearchService);
            window.onbeforeunload = function () { return "You have changed the jobsite location. \r\n If you leave this page the changes will be lost."; };
        }
    };

    function getDirections() {
        var street = document.getElementById("startstreet");
        var city = document.getElementById("startcity");
        var state = document.getElementById("startstate");

        start = street.value + ' ' + city.value + ', ' + state.value;
        Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', { callback: directionsModuleLoaded });
    };


    function deletePushpin() {
        for (var i = map.entities.getLength() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var pushpin = map.entities.get(i);
            if (pushpin instanceof Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin || pushpin instanceof Microsoft.Maps.Polyline) {
                map.entities.removeAt(i);
            };
        }
    };


    endDragDetails = function (e) {
        $(".busyindicator").show();
        var loc = e.entity.getLocation();
        viewModel.latitude(loc.latitude);
        viewModel.longitude(loc.longitude);
        map.getCredentials(getAddressByLongLat);
        window.onbeforeunload = function () { return "You have changed the jobsite location. \r\n If you leave this page the changes will be lost."; };
    };

    function getAddressByLongLat(credentials) {
        var loc = viewModel.latitude() + ',' + viewModel.longitude();
        var searchRequest = 'http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/' + loc + '?output=json&jsonp=addressByLongLatCallback&key=' + credentials;
        var mapscript = document.createElement('script');
        mapscript.type = 'text/javascript';
        mapscript.src = searchRequest;
        document.getElementById('myMap').appendChild(mapscript)
    };

    function addressByLongLatCallback(result) {
        var output = document.getElementById("output");
        if (output) {
            while (output.hasChildNodes()) {
                output.removeChild(output.lastChild);
            }
        }
        var resultsHeader = document.createElement("h5");
        output.appendChild(resultsHeader);

        if (result &&
          result.resourceSets &&
          result.resourceSets.length > 0 &&
          result.resourceSets[0].resources &&
          result.resourceSets[0].resources.length > 0) {

            resultsHeader.innerHTML = "Location Updated " + result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].name;

            var countyName = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].address.adminDistrict2;
            if (countyName) {
                if (countyName.length !== 0) {
                    if (countyName.indexOf('Co.') > 0) {
                        countyName = countyName.substring(0, countyName.length - 4);
                    };
                };
            };

            viewModel.street(result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].address.addressLine);
            viewModel.city(result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].address.locality);
            viewModel.state(result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].address.adminDistrict);
            viewModel.county(countyName);
            viewModel.zipcode(result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].address.postalCode);
            viewModel.country(result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].address.countryRegion);                       
        }
        else {
            if (typeof (response) == 'undefined' || response == null) {
                alert("Invalid credentials or no response");
            }
            else {
                if (typeof (response) != 'undefined' && response && result && result.errorDetails) {
                    resultsHeader.innerHTML = "Message :" + response.errorDetails[0];
                }
                alert("No results for the query");

            }
        }
        $(".busyindicator").hide();
    }

    function callSearchService(credentials) {
        var searchRequest = 'http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/' + query + '?output=json&jsonp=searchServiceCallback&key=' + credentials;
        var mapscript = document.createElement('script');
        mapscript.type = 'text/javascript';
        mapscript.src = searchRequest;
        document.getElementById('myMap').appendChild(mapscript)
    };

    function searchServiceCallback(result) {
        var output = document.getElementById("output");
        if (output) {
            while (output.hasChildNodes()) {
                output.removeChild(output.lastChild);
            }
        }
        var resultsHeader = document.createElement("h5");
        output.appendChild(resultsHeader);

        if (result &&
          result.resourceSets &&
          result.resourceSets.length > 0 &&
          result.resourceSets[0].resources &&
          result.resourceSets[0].resources.length > 0) {
            resultsHeader.innerHTML = "Found location " + result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].name;
            var bbox = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].bbox;
            var viewBoundaries = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(bbox[0], bbox[1]), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(bbox[2], bbox[3]));
            map.setView({ bounds: viewBoundaries });
            var location = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].point.coordinates[0], result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].point.coordinates[1]);
            var pushpinOptions = { draggable: true };
            var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(location, pushpinOptions);
            var pushpindragend = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin, 'dragend', endDragDetails); 
            map.entities.push(pushpin);


            var countyName = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].address.adminDistrict2;
            if (countyName) {
                if (countyName.length !== 0) {
                    if (countyName.indexOf('Co.') > 0) {
                        countyName = countyName.substring(0, countyName.length - 4);
                    };
                };
            };

            viewModel.street(result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].address.addressLine);
            viewModel.city(result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].address.locality);
            viewModel.state(result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].address.adminDistrict);
            viewModel.county(countyName);
            viewModel.zipcode(result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].address.postalCode);
            viewModel.country(result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].address.countryRegion);   


            viewModel.latitude(location.latitude);
            viewModel.longitude(location.longitude);
        }
        else {
            if (typeof (response) == 'undefined' || response == null) {
                alert("Invalid credentials or no response");
            }
            else {
                if (typeof (response) != 'undefined' && response && result && result.errorDetails) {
                    resultsHeader.innerHTML = "Message :" + response.errorDetails[0];
                }
                alert("No results for the query");

            }
        }
    };

    function directionsModuleLoaded() {
        // Initialize the DirectionsManager
        directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);

        var lat = document.getElementById("latitude");
        var long = document.getElementById("longitude");

        // Create start and end waypoints
        var startWaypoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: start });
        var endWaypoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(lat.value, long.value) });

        directionsManager.addWaypoint(startWaypoint);
        directionsManager.addWaypoint(endWaypoint);

        // Set request options
        directionsManager.setRequestOptions({ distanceUnit: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DistanceUnit.miles, routeOptimization: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteOptimization.shortestDistance });

        // Set the render options
        directionsManager.setRenderOptions({ itineraryContainer: document.getElementById('output') });

        // Specify a handler for when an error occurs
        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(directionsManager, 'directionsError', displayError);

        // Calculate directions, which displays a route on the map
        directionsManager.calculateDirections();

    };

    function displayError(e) {
        // Display the error message
        alert(e.message);
    };



    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            activate: function (event, ui) {
                viewModel.updateInputScreen(ui.newTab.context.id);
            }
        });
        $("#findlocation").validate(
        {
            errorLabelContainer: "#errorMessages",
            wrapper: "li",

            rules: {
                street: { required: true },
                city: { required: true },
                state: { required: true }
            },
            messages: {
                street: { required: "Street is required." },
                city: { required: "City is required." },
                state: { required: "State is required." }
            }

        });
        getMap();
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who comes looking in the future, what I found is that the div where the map is to post needs to have a Height and Width style defining it.

The error with the async method where Microsoft is undefined will continue to happen, but the map works.

Here's the odd part and I didn't realize this until I started to switch to v8...this error was happening in ver 7 too. In fact until a few days ago, ver 7 was still working using the same code.

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

- Your JavaScript to load the map is not in a script tag.
- You should consider moving the map script tag below your map load JavaScript, as it is possible that if the map control is cached, it will fire the callback before the GetMap function has been loaded into the page. This often happens if you press the refresh button.
- Also, the mapTypeId should be Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.**road** with a small "r" not a capital.
- When you have a float style, you have to specify a width/height as their is no way to determine this dynamically.
- Width/Height/enableSearchLogo are not map options in V8. This wouldn't cause an issue and would simply be ignored, but something you can remove to simplify your code.